# In iOS, Why [[NSDate date]timeIntervalSince1970] is double internally? It should be long long though

Tags: ios, nsdate, nstimeinterval

In iOS SDK, I observed that `[[NSDate date]timeIntervalSince1970]` returns `NSTimeInterval` which is double internally. Ideally shouldn't it be long long?

Answer (score 1):

Picking a representation for `NSTimeInterval` is a tradeoff between precision and ease of use.

Picking `long long` would require using a time unit other than second - say, a millisecond or a microsecond, and then providing functions or macros for extracting time units from the interval.

Cocoa designers went for ease of use, requiring that `NSTimeInterval` is always specified in seconds. This gives you sub-millisecond precision over a range of 10,000 years, which is good enough for most applications.

Answer (score 0):

From [apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_DataTypes/#//apple_ref/c/tdef/NSTimeInterval):

```
NSTimeInterval is always specified in seconds; it yields sub-millisecond precision over a range of 10,000 years.
```

NSTimeInterval represents a **time dimension** value which is not always a decimal number. So the NSTimeInterval must be fractional too.

In 64-bit systems **CGFloat** and **long long** [has the same size](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaTouch64BitGuide/Major64-BitChanges/Major64-BitChanges.html) – 8 bytes.